# setting the background Size of div tag not working using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-size

I need to change the size of a background image during an animation but it doesn't work.

Here is a simple version of my code:

```js
document.querySelector("#Box").backgroundSize='cover';
```

```css
#Box {
  background-image: url(https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg);
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="Box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should target the `.style`

```js
document.querySelector("#Box").style.backgroundSize='cover';
```

```css
#Box {
  background-image: url(https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg);
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="Box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the .style declaration in your query selector

```js
document.querySelector("#Box").style.backgroundSize='cover';
```

```css
#Box {
  background-image: url(https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg);
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="Box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just missing `style` from your js...

```js
document.querySelector("#Box").style.backgroundSize='cover';
```

```css
#Box {
  background-image: url(https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg);
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="Box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#Box` element have no backgroundSize property. You should just refer to its style property and then to backgroundSize

```
document.querySelector("#Box").style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
```